# how to serialize HTML form data which is inside php loop

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML form which is inside PHP loop and trying to send that form data via ajax.

If the php loop executes 3 times, all the form data is sent out.

tried to update the form name dynamically. but not aware of how to send that via ajax.

HTML form: this form is inside php loop

```
<form action="" method="post" name="cartForm">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $row['productID']; ?>" />                                      
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button btn"  onclick="addCartFun()" />
</form>
```

Ajax call:

```
function addCartFun(){
$.ajax({
url: '/cartHand.php',
 type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: $("form[name=cartForm]").serialize(),
success: function(){
}
});
}
```

I expect that if I click that submit button, only data corresponding to the form has to be sent.
Thanks.

Comment: put your form out of the loop,

Comment: There's an issue with your JQuery selector: `$("form[name=cartForm")`.

Comment: Create different names for each form in the loop, and instead of using `$("form[name=cartForm")`, try using the `this` keyword. However, I couldn't tell you which would be the correct syntax right off the bat... Or pass the dynamically generated form name into the function, and use that in your data selector.

Comment: its not working. my UI will get collapsed if I change form out of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine now. I dynamically generated the form name and made that ajax call inside the call inside the loop. Thanks.

AJAX call:

```
$("form[name=<?php echo $formName ?>]").submit(function({ 
 $.ajax({
  url: '/cartHand.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(){}
  });
});
```

Form Name:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="<?php echo $formName ?>"></form>
```